# Symmetric projection method (Geometric integration on manifolds)

Tags: ode, rigid-bodies, symmetric

I am studying the transition of numerical methods from the classical setting to the manifold case in the context of geometric numerical integration. Precisely, I am studying the paper "GEOMETRIC INTEGRATION OF ORDINARY DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS ON MANIFOLDS" (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1021989212020), and I am trying to reproduce the numerical examples.
My struggle is with algorithm 3.2, the Symmetric projection method.
Can anyone provide a Python script of the implementation of such method for the Rigid body example presented in the paper, considering the classical trapezoidal method as the one-step method in the second bullet point?

[Picture of the algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tdXi.png)
.

Comment: What is preventing you from writing it yourself?

Comment: I have implemented the classical trapezoidal rule and algorithm 3.1, by projecting the solution on the manifold, but when it comes to 3.2, I do not have a clear understanding of the order of the implementation. It says that \mu has to be the same in the perturbation step and the projection step. So, does this mean that I choose a guess for \mu and always use that or do I have to solve for \mu. If yes, I can't figure out how to do the update for both the solution and the \mu.

Comment: Please see also my answer below, where I have provided my code and the plot for the energy.

Comment: Any idea where the mistake could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/preprints/symproj.pdf](http://www.unige.ch/%7Ehairer/preprints/symproj.pdf)

> It is important to take the
> same vector *mu* in (2.1) and (2.3).

where the equations 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 describe the method as cited.

Which means that the method is implicit in *mu*. One can choose how exact the approximation for *mu* has to be, if it always has to be computed via Newton or if some fixed-point iteration is sufficient, if the Jacobian *G* needs to be computed in every step, etc.

---

If you are using a general-purpose non-linear solver, then it is better to implement an all-at-once approach, and not alternate the search directions.

Instead assemble state `y1` and perturbation parameters `mu` into one input vector for the function serving as non-linear system in `fsolve` and return the residual of the RK step, here again the trapezoidal method, and the residuals of the first integrals, with the exact value being set to zero.

```python
def residuals(u):
    y1, mu = u[:sdim], u[sdim,:]
    y0mu = y0 + G(y0).T @ mu
    y1mu = y1 - G(y1).T @ mu
    f0mu = f(y0mu)
    f1mu = f(y1mu)
    restrap = (y1mu-y0mu)/dt - 0.5*(f0mu+f1mu)
    resfirst = g(y1)
    return [*restrap, *resfirst]
```

This is more pseudo-code than directly executable. The passing of parameters can be made more explicit, using the `args` keyword parameter of `fsolve`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lutz! I was reading that source (from the same author) as well. My confusion is that the method is implicit in mu (for the reason you mentioned), but the one-step method in 2.2 is also implicit in (y1).

Comment: In one of the answers below, I have added my code and the plot for the energy. 
PS: I still need to figure out how to use stack, to properly comment, answer, include code and pictures.

Comment: Any idea where the mistake could be?

Comment: Your error is that you implement the one-sided projection, and the energy shows that.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Lutz! Your suggestion helped indeed and I got the expected behaviour of the energy now.